# SQL Server select query performance tuning

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a performance issue with a select query. The query can take more than 4 minutes which is too long and the SQL Server table has 5 billions records.

Here is the query:

```
Select
    ID,Name,City,locationfile,locationpath
From
    Table
where 
    locationfile like '%euro%'`
```

Output results: 90,000 rows returned in 4 mins.

Clustered Index on ID primaryKey

Nonclustered covered Index created on locationfile include (City,locationpath)

Here is the stats: logical reads 10 070 208, physical reads 2, read-ahead 10 051 119

How to improve the performance to get the results?

Comment: Have you looked at full text search?

Comment: An index on `locationfile` without any included columns would allow for fewer reads to complete an index _scan_, but `like '%euro%'` will always require a scan (rather than a _lookup_) due to the leading wildcard.

Comment: We may not  implement full index text search at this moment..,,

Comment: HABO:Your suggestion is  to create an non clustered index on locationfile without include column?..

Comment: Any explanation for `We may not implement full index text search at this moment`? Are there other things you may not implement?

Comment: Your index is not covering because it doesn't have `Name` in it. Adding it can improve performance, although this might as well scan the clustered index, unless the table is really wide.

Comment: @Kusu Given that your `where` clause only references `locationfile` and returns 90,000 rows out of 5,000,000,000 there doesn't appear to be any benefit to using a covering index, you simply want the fastest scan possible. An index on `locationfile` without included columns will provide the most entries per page and thus require the fewest read operations. The additional I/O overhead to retrieve the selected columns for 0.002% of the table rows is insignificant. Similarly, there is no reason to bother clustering on `locationfile`.

Comment: @HABO  I have implemented the non clustered index on  locationfile without included any columns and still the performance is same 4 mins 10 seconds...Any other suggestions...

Comment: @Martin Smith:I wanted to fine tune the query only..Does loading into multiple tables will help..instead of single table..

Comment: The problem is that the only thing that will _really_ speed up `locationfile like '%euro%'` is full text search. No index will speed it up. If you can remove the leading `%` then an index on it will actually help.

Comment: I had created 80 tables and loaded in to 80 tables then the performance improved a lot took 1:40 secs to get the results..However 1:40 secs is not acceptable..Can you please let me what percentage of time improvements with full text search would be possible..

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY cannot implement FTS, here is my somewhat crazy suggestion to force index usage:

1) check how many chars locationfile has and what is the maximum charindex where that substring 'euro' can appear in that string. Let N be that number.

2) create N generated persisted columns locationfile1, locationfile2, ..., with values substring(1, len(locationfile)), substring(2, len(locationfile))  ,etc

3)create indexes for all these columns and locationfile

4) use the query
Select
    ID,Name,City,locationfile,locationpath
From
    Table
where 
    locationfile like 'euro%'

UNION

Select
    ID,Name,City,locationfile,locationpath
From
    Table
where 
    locationfile1 like 'euro%'

UNION

Select
    ID,Name,City,locationfile,locationpath
From
    Table
where 
    locationfile2 like 'euro%'

...etc

UNION

Select
    ID,Name,City,locationfile,locationpath
From
    Table
where 
    locationfileN like 'euro%'